# Why does this code hang when I use Console.WriteLine to print an async method's result?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-5.0

This is my code for WPF.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    delegate Task<int> testasync();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        testasync atest = new testasync(async () => { var result = await Thread_sleep(); return result; });
        System.Console.WriteLine("begin");
        System.Console.WriteLine("1");
        System.Console.WriteLine(atest().Result);
        System.Console.WriteLine("3");
    }

    async public Task<int> Thread_sleep()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        return 2;
    }
}
```

I expect the results to be 1,3,2 but it hangs. But, it works when I use the `Thread_sleep` method to print the '2'.

Answer (score 1):

`atest().Result` is a synchronous call, causing a deadlock (the continuation of `await Task.Delay(10)` is trying to run on the UI thread, that is blocked by your call).

Two possible fixes:

1. (prefered solution) Await the result instead of using the `Result` property:

   ```
   var result = await atest();
   System.Console.WriteLine(result);
   ```
2. Change your asynchronous calls so the continuations won't run on the UI thread:

   ```
   await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(false);
   ```

   and

   ```
   var result = await Thread_sleep().ConfigureAwait(false);
   ```

As a rule of thumb, never use `.Result` or `.Wait()` on a task in a WPF application, unless you're absolutely certain that you need to. Always try to use `await` instead.

Comment: thank you.I think I should be more careful to understand what is await in c# :)